# How to enable logging of all chats to a file in AzerothCore?

Tags: azerothcore

I'm trying to enable the logging of all chats to a file, but since the configuration changed from the last time, now I'm struggling to figure how to do it. I have read the wiki article about the new logging system (Loggers and Appenders) and added this line to my conf:

```
Logger.chat.log=4,Chat.log,a
```

But nothing seems to happen.

Could anyone please help me with it?

Thanks!

Edit: So currently my chat log settings look like this:

```
Appender.Chat=2,4,1,chat_%s.log
Logger.chat.log=4,Chat
Logger.chat.system=4,Chat
Logger.chat.say=4,Chat
```

Unfortunately it's not working. There isn't even an empty chat log file in the folder.

I don't understand what I'm doing wrong. I created a new appender `Chat` which points to a file. And also enabled a logger `Logger.chat*` (taken from the conf) pointing to the new appender.

Answer (score 1):

Create new appender if need

```
Appender.Chat=2,5,0,Chat.log
```

And create logger

```
Logger.chat.log=5,Chat
```

Comment: Will this log all chats or I should create appenders/loggers separately for each?

Comment: I actually did what you proposed, and indeed Chat.log have been created but it's empty. I typed in different channels, /say, /w but nothing seems to log into the file.

Answer (score 0):

Appender.Console=1,1,0

Appender.Chat=2,1,1,Chat.log,a

Logger.root=6,Console Server

Logger.chat.log=1,Console Chat

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).